# How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to detect when I have network connectivity over WIFI.  What broadcast is sent to establish that a valid network connection has been made.  I need to validate that a valid network connection for HTTP exists.  What should I listen for and what additional tests do I need to make to know that a valid connection exists.

Comment: Parts of this question have been answered here I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available

Comment: But there is still the question of WHEN to check these conditions?

Comment: I would like feedback on if there are broadcasts that will occur that could be caught by a broadcast receiver?

Comment: How can I do this on Android O as implicit broadcast receivers like android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE will no longer be allowed to be registered in the manifest (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html). If we register it in the application activity (say onCreate), then it will have to be deregistered in onStop(), and we will no longer receive wifi related events

Answer (score 130):

You can register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to be notified when a WiFi connection is established (or if the connection changed).

Register the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And then in your `BroadcastReceiver` do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)) {
            //do stuff
        } else {
            // wifi connection was lost
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, see the documentation for [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)

Of course you should check whether the device is already connected to WiFi before this.

EDIT:
Thanks to ban-geoengineering, here's a method to check whether the device is already connected:

```
private boolean isConnectedViaWifi() {
     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) appObj.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);     
     return mWifi.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Why SUPPLICANT_CONECTION_CHANGE_ACTION? I thought it was JUST CONNECTION_CHANGE change broadcast. Why SUPPLCANT???  thanks

Comment: huh? I don't see an action called connection_change...? I only see wifi state changed but that action only indicates whether wifi is enabled or not (or en-/disabling) not whether it's connected...

is supplicant_connection_change_action not doing what you need?

Comment: For me WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION does not work in case when connection to a known wifi station was established / lost. But WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION does work.

Comment: "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" worked for me. check my answer below

Comment: "Of course you should check whether the device is already connected to WiFi before this." - so, to get the initial Wi-Fi state, you can use this method...
`private boolean isConnectedViaWifi() {
  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) appObj.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
  return mWifi.isConnected();
 }`

Comment: very strange... i tried your code but doesnt work... any clue? @jpm

Comment: @jpm Is isConnectedViaWifi guaranteed to work even though "getNetworkInfo" is deprecated?

Comment: @CamHart I'm not really sure about the latest updates on this topic, but I think you should check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo() and getAllNetworks()
But I haven't worked with these so far...If I've time later I'll check myself and update my answer

Comment: How can I do this on Android O as implicit broadcast receivers like android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE will no longer be allowed to be registered in the manifest (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html). If we register it in the application activity (say onCreate), then it will have to be deregistered in onStop(), and we will no longer receive wifi related events

Comment: @zafar142003 then why not to use a `STICKY` service, and make the context alive.... I tried it, it works. | call `registerReceiver();`

Comment: Is there a way to detect to which Wifi network the device got connected (the SSID or MAC, perhaps) ?

Comment: `SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION` is **deprecated since api level 28**. Use `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGE_ACTION` instead.

Answer (score 107):

The best that worked for me:

#### AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.AEDesign.communication.WifiReceiver" >
   <intent-filter android:priority="100">
      <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

#### BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
      if(info != null && info.isConnected()) {
        // Do your work. 

        // e.g. To check the Network Name or other info:
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
      }
   }
}
```

#### Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer for specifically wifi state chage. Thanks

Comment: For future easy reference, that hardcoded action is [WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION).

Comment: if (info != null && info.isConnected()) = no spaghetti.

Comment: do we need to write any code to send broadcast in main activity??

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />` is also required and needs to included right? @usman

Comment: How can I do this on Android O as implicit broadcast receivers like android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE will no longer be allowed to be registered in the manifest (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html). If we register it in the application activity (say onCreate), then it will have to be deregistered in onStop(), and we will no longer receive wifi related events.

Comment: great discussion but in my case, I want to get broadcast right after user enables wifi button from settings.
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE is called when wifi is connected to a device and its late for me.

Answer (score 18):

For me only [`WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) works.

Register a broadcast receiver:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and receive:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)){
        NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        boolean connected = info.isConnected();

        //call your method
    }      
}
```

Comment: For me as well only WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION worked, any explanations for the reason why only this will work?

Answer (score 10):

You **can** start a wifi connection if you give the user a choice to override the normal behavior of asking each time.

I choose to use three methods...

```
public boolean isOnline() 
{
 ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

This is quick check if  there is an internet connect either Wifi or CellData. From here you can choose what action you want to take. Is it in Airplane mode needs to be checked also.

On a separate thread.
I set a variable IpAddress to = " "
And poll until I have a valid an ip address.

```
  WifiManager wifi;
  wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
  int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
  String ip = null;
  ip = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",
  (ipAddress & 0xff),
  (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
  (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),
  (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
  Log.e(" >>IP number Begin ",ip);
```

Another code snippet... If its not on turn it on (with users prior permission)

```
   if(wifi.isWifiEnabled()!=true)wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 10):

Answer given by user @JPM and @usman are really very useful. It works fine but in my case it come in `onReceive` multiple time in my case **4 times** so my code execute multiple time.

I do some modification and make as per my requirement and now it comes only 1 time

Here is java class for Broadcast.

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mContext = context;


    if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI &&
                networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Wifi is connected
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

            Log.e(TAG, " -- Wifi connected --- " + " SSID " + ssid );

        }
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
    {
        int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
        if (wifiState == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, " ----- Wifi  Disconnected ----- ");
        }

    }
}
}
```

**In AndroidManifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".util.WifiReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: what is wifiState?

Comment: Would also like to know what wifiState is, how it was generated

Comment: @behelit  now "wifiState" is there in edited answer.

Comment: This answer will not work as of api v26. Official docs says: This broadcast is not delivered to manifest receivers in applications that target API version 26 or later.

Answer (score 8):

To detect WIFI connection state, I have used CONNECTIVITY_ACTION from ConnectivityManager class so:

```
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

and from your BroadCastReceiver:

```
    if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        int networkType = intent.getIntExtra(
                android.net.ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_TYPE, -1);
        if (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI == networkType) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (networkInfo != null) {
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                    // TODO: wifi is connected
                } else {
                    // TODO: wifi is not connected
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

ps:works fine for me:)

Comment: fyi, with Android 6 when you have a valid cell data connection, changes in wifi state won't trigger CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.  The only reason they did is connectivity state was impacted, now it isn't.

Comment: CONNECTIVITY_ACTION: "This constant was deprecated in API level 28. apps should use the more versatile requestNetwork(NetworkRequest, PendingIntent), registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest, PendingIntent) or registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) functions instead for faster and more detailed updates about the network changes they care about."

Answer (score 5):

This code does not require permission at all. It is restricted only to Wi-Fi network connectivity state changes (any other network is not taken into account). The receiver is statically published in the AndroidManifest.xml file and does not need to be exported as it will be invoked by the system [`protected broadcast`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), [`NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION), at every network connectivity state change.

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".WifiReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter>
        <!--protected-broadcast: Special broadcast that only the system can send-->
        <!--Corresponds to: android.net.wifi.WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION-->
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver class:**

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
/*
 Tested (I didn't test with the WPS "Wi-Fi Protected Setup" standard):
 In API15 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) this method is called when the new Wi-Fi network state is:
 DISCONNECTED, OBTAINING_IPADDR, CONNECTED or SCANNING

 In API19 (KITKAT) this method is called when the new Wi-Fi network state is:
 DISCONNECTED (twice), OBTAINING_IPADDR, VERIFYING_POOR_LINK, CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK
 or CONNECTED

 (Those states can be obtained as NetworkInfo.DetailedState objects by calling
 the NetworkInfo object method: "networkInfo.getDetailedState()")
*/
    /*
     * NetworkInfo object associated with the Wi-Fi network.
     * It won't be null when "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" action intent arrives.
     */
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // TODO: Place the work here, like retrieving the access point's SSID

        /*
         * WifiInfo object giving information about the access point we are connected to.
         * It shouldn't be null when the new Wi-Fi network state is CONNECTED, but it got
         * null sometimes when connecting to a "virtualized Wi-Fi router" in API15.
         */
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    }
}
}
```

**Permissions:**

```
None
```

Comment: The works in devices running < API 26.
As @Isham suggested the action is no longer supported in Android O

Answer (score 5):

**November 2020:**

I have dealt too much with items deprecated by Google. Finally I found a solution to my particular requirement using "registerNetworkCallback" as Google currently suggests.

What I needed was a simple way to detect that my device has an IPv4 assigned in WIFI.
(I haven't tried other cases, my requirement was very specific, but maybe this method, without deprecated elements, will serve as a basis for other cases).

Tested on APIs 23, 24 and 26 (physical devices) and APIs 28 and 29 (emulated devices).

```
    ConnectivityManager cm 
            = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

    cm.registerNetworkCallback
            (
                    builder.build(),
                    new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onAvailable(Network network)
                        {
                            //Actions to take with Wifi available.
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onLost(Network network)
                        {
                            //Actions to take with lost Wifi.
                        }
                    }

            );
```

(Implemented inside "MainActivity.Oncreate")

Note: In manifest needs "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

Comment: I've been using the deprecated version and have noticed a deficiency - I can detect if the wifi is truly out, but not if the wifi is working properly and the router it is attached to is not.   Does the new call back indicate whether or not you can actually communicate the internet? Or like before only see the SSID

Comment: @Martin I'm sorry. I use this method only to detect if the device has an assigned IPv4 (calling another function from "onAvailable"). I don't check if there is internet or not. Internet is not a requirement specifically in my project. I'm sure there must be other appropriate methods to verify internet access that can probably be invoked from "onAvailable" as well.

Comment: Both `onLost()` and `onUnavailable()` doesn't get called when first time launches the app with no internet connection. Any suggestion?

Comment: @SamChen You're right. The "onAvailable ()" and "onLost ()" functions are not called if the app starts with Wifi not established. But "onAvailable ()" is actually called if the application starts with an established Wifi connection. So, I initialize my app in a "Wifi not established" state. If in fact there is no Wifi, my application will remain in the "Wifi not established" state. But if when starting my application it finds that there is an established Wifi connection, the "onAvailable" function will be called and it will change my application to the "Wifi established" state.

Comment: @cesargastonec Wow, you're genius! Using a `Boolean` to indicate the connection state and initialize to false, good idea.

Comment: @cesargastonec Sadly this doesn't work for me, but I found my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573565/android-get-status-of-wifi-connection/66648761

Answer (score 4):

Android O removed the possibility to receive the implicit broadcasts for a wifi state change. So if your app is closed, you'll not be able to receive them. The new `WorkManager` has the ability to run when your app is closed, so I've experimented a bit with it and it seems to work quite well:

Add this to your dependencies:

```
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha08"
```

*WifiConnectWorker.kt*

```
class WifiConnectWorker : Worker() {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.i(TAG, "I think we connected to a wifi")
        return Result.SUCCESS
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.kt*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()

        // Add constraint to start the worker when connecting to WiFi
        val request = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WifiConnectWorker::class.java)
            .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(UNMETERED)
                .build())
            .build()

        // The worker should be started, even if your app is closed
        workManager.beginUniqueWork("watch_wifi", REPLACE, request).enqueue()
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this was just a quick test for a one-time notification. There is more work to do to always get notified when WiFi is turned on and off.

PS: When the app is *force quit*, the worker is not started, it seems `WorkManager` is canceling the requests then.

Comment: Is there any way to start worker even if my app is force quited state. Work manager is working with .setRequiredNetworkType(UNMETERED) only if the app is open. Is there any way to trigger worker even app is in killed(force closed state). Because implicit broad cast receiver also somewhat restricted. What will be the best alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of my code, that takes into account the users preference of only allowing comms when connected to Wifi.

I am calling this code from inside an `IntentService` before I attempt to download stuff.

Note that `NetworkInfo` will be `null` if there is no network connection of any kind.

```
private boolean canConnect()
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    boolean canConnect = false;
    boolean wifiOnly = SharedPreferencesUtils.wifiOnly();

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo != null)
    {
        if(networkInfo.isConnected())
        {
            if((networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) ||
               (networkInfo.getType() != ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && !wifiOnly))
            {
                canConnect = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return canConnect;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**I have two methods to detect WIFI connection receiving the application context:**

#### 1)my old method

```
public boolean isConnectedWifi1(Context context) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();           
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
                if ((ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                        && ni.isConnected()) {
                    return true;
                }                   
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### 2)my New method (I´m currently using this method):

```
public boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
         ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);     
         return networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: How can I do this on Android O as implicit broadcast receivers like android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE will no longer be allowed to be registered in the manifest (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html). If we register it in the application activity (say onCreate), then it will have to be deregistered in onStop(), and we will no longer receive wifi related events

Answer (score 3):

1) I tried Broadcast Receiver approach as well even though I know [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION/CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) is deprecated in API 28 and not recommended. Also bound to using explicit register, it listens as long as app is running.

2) I also tried Firebase Dispatcher which works but not beyond app killed.

3) Recommended way found is WorkManager to guarantee execution beyond process killed and internally using [registerNetworkRequest()](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#monitor-conn)

The biggest evidence in favor of #3 approach is referred by [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#monitor-conn) itself. Especially for apps in the background.

Also [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0#background_optimizations)

> In Android 7.0 we're removing three commonly-used implicit broadcasts — CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, ACTION_NEW_PICTURE, and ACTION_NEW_VIDEO — since those can wake the background processes of multiple apps at once and strain memory and battery. If your app is receiving these, take advantage of the Android 7.0 to migrate to JobScheduler and related APIs instead.

So far it works fine for us using Periodic WorkManager request.

Update: I ended up writing 2 series [medium post](https://medium.com/ki-labs-engineering/monitoring-wifi-connectivity-status-part-1-c5f4287dd57) about it.

Answer (score 2):

I used this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .
        .
        .
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
        {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);  
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
        {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }

    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION))
                {
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false))
                    {
                    // wifi is enabled
                    }
                else
                    {
                    // wifi is disabled
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For all those who enjoying **CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE** broadcast, please note this is no more fired when app is in background in Android O.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/o/background.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Broadcast With Filter

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.ConnectionType"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

after that, you can listen to the value returned like that

```
  @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
    if(wifiState==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED){
        Toast.makeText(context, "WIFI on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else if(wifiState==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "WIFI OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

it will fire every time WIFI enabled or disabled

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Extension Function

```
val Context.isOnline: Boolean
    get() {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager

        if (cm != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                val networkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
                if (networkInfo != null) {
                    return networkInfo.isConnected && (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE ||
                            networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN || networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET)
                }
            } else {
                val network = cm.activeNetwork

                if (network != null) {
                    val nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                    return if (nc == null) {
                        false
                    } else {
                        nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                                nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
                                nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) ||
                                nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```