# Android: Get the time wifi is connected

Tags: android, android-wifi

Do you guys know how to get the wifi connection time(the time the phone is connected to wifi)?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but probably this is what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established

Comment: Thanks @Egor.. It helps..but is there anyway i can get the value without registering a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @Zul, Did you find a way to get it without broadcasts?