# Download pdf from remote server

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app which needs to push pdf files into server from mobile and same time download those files from server in different mobiles when wifi available...so help me some start up...

Comment: what did you tried till now?

Comment: i have done download images from images and display in my app...and now want to move this to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You should give more information, but this is what I would do if I had the resource available via a URL on the server.

If you just want to view it on the device:

> startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(some-url)));

If you want to download it and do something else with it then use Java sockets to connect to the server and get the file.

To know when WiFi has become available you need to register a BroadcastReceiver so that your activity gets notified when WiFi's connection state changes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established) you have a post where the top answer shows an example of how to do that.

Comment: Thank You Juan..i got downloaded PDF from url into sd card...it will do by giving the url with particular pdf name..i want to download all the files available from server when wifi enables...

Comment: You need to register a BroadcastReceiver to notify you that the connection state has changed. I'll edit my post.