# Wait for network connection

Tags: java, android

I need to make my app wait until a wifi connection is fully established and only then continue to run.
I have this code for now:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connecting to wifi network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        //wait for connection to be establisihed and only then proceed


    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a broadcast receiver registered for:

```
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

listen the status changes and keep a variable with the current status

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges)

---

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.WifiReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And the Receiver:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean connected = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = mgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}

public boolean isConnected(){
    return connected; 
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate? How can i make the Main Thread wait for the receiver response?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of blocking the main thread, you could introduce **a screen to the users** with a connection **notification** to let them know what's happening.

While showing a screen with the notification you could check for a connection using the

> **ConnectivityManager**

Note that checking only a WIFI connection **will not guarantee** a data service. Network issues, server downtime, authorization, etc. could always occur.

Example of usage:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Also, don't forget to add the right **permission**:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

You can find more about this on the Android Developer website:
[Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Good luck.