# how to send data to the server in android on wifi only

Tags: android

How can I detect if `WiFi` is switched on to decide whether to transfer data to the server via android client or not?

On the android device using web services, first the android device checks that `WiFi` is on or off, and when the `WiFi` is switched off data should be stored in database or some other resource and as soon as the WiFi is turned on/or become available data should be started to transfer to the server.

What should be used to implement this?

Answer (score 5):

You can check whether `WiFi` is turned on or not. Just include a code like this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (ni.isConnected())
  Log.d("WifiOn", "Wifi is connected");
else
  Log.d("WifiOn", "Wifi is not connected");
```

In order to make this work, don't forget to put this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

If you don't have Wifi enabled, you can store the data in a local `SQLite` database and as soon as you detect a configuration change, store the data through net. To know how to detect a configuration change, you might look at this question:

- [How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android)