# Trigger some code as soon as android app detects a particular Wi-Fi network

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

Im developing an android app. For this app to work the Wi-Fi needs to be enabled all the time. Because the Wi-Fi is enabled it will keep on scanning for available networks.

I want some function to be called as soon as the Wi-Fi connects to a particular network.
How do I achieve this?

I have written the following code but this works only once, how do I make this scan for networks continuously?

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                      NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                      if(wifi.isConnected()){
                          final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                            final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                            if (connectionInfo != null && !(connectionInfo.getSSID().equals(""))) {
                              String ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
                            }
                          Log.i("wifi", "connected");
                      }
                      else{
                          Log.i("wifi", "not connected");
                      }
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps and do a trick

1) Create NetworkChangeReceiver

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean isWifiConnected = true;
    public static final String tag = "NETWORKCHANGERECEIVER";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifi.isConnected()) {
            final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            if (connectionInfo != null && !(connectionInfo.getSSID().equals(""))) {
                String ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
            }
            isWifiConnected = true;
            Log.i("wifi", "connected");
        } else {
            Log.i("wifi", "not connected");
            isWifiConnected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Add this line to Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <receiver android:name="com.df.src.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Comment: I have implemented NetworkChangeReceiver class as an inner class. Now, how do I use it?

Comment: DO not use it as inner class put it as outer class

Comment: I did as you said. And it worked! I would like to know that how can I use the data generated by NetworkChangeReceiver like the ssid in my MainActivity class?

Comment: Accept the answer so other people can use it

Comment: thanks for upvote the answer but you should accept as well to make answer more effective

Answer (score 0):

You should use a BroadcastReceiver in your application to get instant notifications about connectivity changes.

Some reference that may help you:

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/

http://developerandro.blogspot.com/2013/09/check-internet-connection-using.html?m=1

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html