# BroadcastReceiver issue only on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I'm developing an Android app which should be able to detect the time when the device gets connected to a WiFi network. it implements that based on `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION`([code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890553/1986618)). it works fine on different Android versions except for Android 4.4.2. on this version the receiver didn't receive any action. why?!

Comment: I have the exact same problem with my app. If you have a solution i'd be happy to know.