# How I do During WI-FI Connecting , showing progress dialog on android?

Tags: android

recently I have WI-FI connecter code .
and I add if wi-fi connect button click, showing dialog.
but showing dialog continued remains.
I want when WI-FI connecting showing dialog, and completed wifi connect ,dismiss dialog.

I try this. but is I don't know error logcat.

How programatically showing progress dialog when wifi connecting ?

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        final WifiConfiguration config = Wifi.getWifiConfiguration(mWifiManager, mScanResult, mScanResultSecurity);
        boolean connResult = false;

        if (config != null) {
            connResult = Wifi.connectToConfiguredNetwork(mFloating, mWifiManager, config, false);   //WI-FI 연결
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);


            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    //NullPointerException this line 
            NetworkInfo wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if(wifi.isConnected()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }else {
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
        if (!connResult) {
            Toast.makeText(mFloating, R.string.toastFailed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

};
```

2. try

`Context context;  //global variable 
 ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);   //Null pointer Exception
                NetworkInfo wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                if(wifi.isConnected()){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }else {
                    dialog.show();
                }`

please perhaps need information, advice for me
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a BroadcastReceiver to wait for wifi connect callback, see [How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android)

Comment: first, I try this. perhaps if I don't understands ask for you   . thank :)

Comment: Also if you mean you get null pointer exception on NetworkInfo wifi = ..., you do you have permission to ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE? see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(int) , it may return null

Comment: my wifi-connecter button click class   is onCreate method none.        so I create

Comment: `@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
}`

Comment: ` @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    dialog.show();`

Comment: but I try isConnectedViaWifi(){   `ConnectivityManager connectivityManager  this line NPE ERROR

Comment: If your NetworkInfo wifi is null pointer error, it mean it is not connected, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html you need to check for null, not only isConnected()

Comment: huh.. I check for null.   `ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();`                                                                                      first,NPE is disappear   but   `java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`    exception

Comment: I weired ..   my class not oncreate  and extends class is abstract class .