# android specific wifi connected volume down

Tags: android, wifi

i have a list off wifi i want when i conected to specific wifi my phone volume auto down how to do this i am new in android

```
private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
            wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
        }
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wifis));
    }
}
```

here is the code of wifi which show me on list i want when specific wifi is connected my phone auto profile change to silent . thanks in advance

Comment: what you need is to look at AudioManager class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).

Comment: but how can i set it with speific wifi?

Comment: Use broadcast receiver to receive wifi changes updates, then when it is connected, write volume code there. Broadcast Receiver for wifi is [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5890553/4856761)

Comment: will you please tell me with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if wifi is connected:

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();


    if (connectionInfo != null && !StringUtil.isBlank(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {

        if(connectionInfo.getSSID()=="MyWifiName")
        {
            AudioManager myAudioManager;
            myAudioManager =  (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            // set silent mode 
            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);       

        }
    }
```

You will need to add Wifi Access State permission in manifest file.

Comment: like i want only my home wifi is connected volume auto increase and when iam out of home volume auto decrease

Comment: only i can use my wifi name just?

Comment: Dude, you can specify any wifi name, just set that YourWifiName string value to your desired name.

Comment: See updated answer, it has fixed wifi connection check code and also setting silent mode code, accept as answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: Try to google out "how can we get string from edittext?" , you will get your answers immediately for these simple questions. [Hint: EditText has getText() and setText() methods] :)