# Generating a number after connecting to wifi

Tags: java, android

I am beginner to android and developing an app. I connect to any particular wifi connection in my app. I want to generate a number like 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.
That number I need for some other purpose. How to do this?

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
    if(wifiInfo.getIpAddress() != 0) {
        if((wifiInfo.getIpAddress() == wifiIp) && (wifiInfo.getSSID().equals(wifiSSID))) {

            if (enableLogs)

        } else{
            if (enableLogs)
                wifiIp = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
            wifiSSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();

}
```

Comment: What about your sample code? It doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a random number then use this:-

```
final int min = 10;
final int max = 100;
final int random = Random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Comment: can you send me full code..i dont no how to use it..or sample code

Comment: You may refer to this link for more:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android