# Broadcast receiver not working when app is closed (from everywhere)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

My App is not
**Receiving** broadcast when **wifi state changes**(connected or disconnected). It is working when app interface is seeing else not

My manifest:
[image]

I created subclass of BroadcastReceiver and declared in manifest , no need of register BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo.State detailedState = networkInfo.getState();


            if (detailedState == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                   ---do something----
                }
                else if(detailedState == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {

                    ---do something----
                }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: are you running the app on android O?

Comment: On which api level you are testing? and whats your target Api Level of app ?

Comment: api 19 and above not android O

Comment: on your is it sendBroadcast(intent)? if so, add , null after intent.

Comment: I'm not using sendBroadcast(intent)

Comment: Refer to answers from this https://stackoverflow.com/q/5888502/1457952

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when WIFI Connection has been established in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android)

Comment: send your code snnipest

Comment: Thank all for this, but i m still there

Comment: try this https://github.com/devggaurav/BroadcastReceiver-For-Naught-and-Oreo-devices