# Android O WifiManager.enableNetwork() cannot work

Tags: android

Fist of all, I manually set up two wifi with my phone, then I use `WifiManager.enableNetwork()` I can successfully switch wifi, but after a few seconds, wifi switches back to the previous wifi, what is the reason? 
please tell me.

> Device: ASUS ZenFone 5 (Android 8.0.0)

Code:

```
void connectWiFi(String networkSSID) {
    int networkId = getNetworkId(networkSSID);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
}

int getNetworkId(String ssid) {
    List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration config : configurations) {
        if (config.SSID != null && config.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
            return config.networkId;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Probably the other network has not good signal level, and that's why it switches to old one? Your English is OK for me BTW.

Comment: Thank you for your amendment, wifi signal is very good, manually switch wifi can also be properly connected, but using "WifiManager.enableNetwork()" will have the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

First, use the broadcast to listen to WiFi disconnect, then use `wifiManager.disconnect()`, wait for the broadcast to disconnect, and then use `wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true)`.

Comment: what can I say, I love you

Comment: What do you mean "wait for the broadcast to disconnect"? Can you please add a code sample?

Comment: @ElJazouli, can you elaborate on how you solved that? The OP hasn't been online for a long time.

Comment: @Keselme @Lance it's been soo long since I've done that so I don't quite remember, but if it was me reading this a year ago I would say there is a broadcast receiver that listens for wifi connect/disconnect actions, and then at some point if you want to connect to a wifi you'd need to call `wifiManager.disconnect()` first and once you get the callback on the broadcast receiver then you connect to the desired wifi.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established-in-android