# How to detect when user turn one wifi connection to other wifi?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I have problem with WiFi connection detection. My goal is to detect when user is switching between different WiFis. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890553/6352712), but it only detects when WiFi was established. In my case I need to know when one WiFi network changed to another on phone.

Comment: once you get that notification, just check if the current wifi name is equal to previous one, and if not - the wifi network changed

Comment: Use `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` for your BroadcastReceiver. It will give you a `CONNECTED` message. Then you can check as @VladyslavMatviienko suggested.

Comment: thanks @Ben i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                if(netInfo.isConnected()) {
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getAplicationContext().getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
                    String ssid  = info.getSSID();
                    Log.d("Wifi Connected", "Wifi name is "+ info.getSSID());
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question at all. They want to detect the switch from one network to another not check if they are connected to a Wifi.

Comment: @Eugen add name wifi check please and i will aprove you answer

Comment: @Eugen my studio recomends to use context?.applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)   instead context?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)

Comment: it is just little note