# After wakeup wifi is not available in the first couple of seconds

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wake-lock

My app is pinned and after waking up device all network requests that are made right away fail with a connection timeout. Waiting a couple of 100ms or seconds does the trick and everything works normally after that.

I suppose there's a small window of time when wifi is "re-enabled". Whats the best way to detect that event?

Android version 4.4 and **wifi sleep is set to "never"**

Comment: To detect wifi connection events, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22626736/986253

Answer (score 0):

As Augusto Ferrarini points out you can listen for broadcast and handle it accordingly. There is a chapter about it on [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring) which I'd recommend reading together with the link from Augusto Ferrarini.